# Submit form with selected options

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit, form-submit, rating

I want to be able to submit a form with selected option.

My backend code is working if I'm using inputs:

```
<input id="id_value_0" name="value" type="radio" value="1" />
<input id="id_value_1" name="value" type="radio" value="2" />
<input id="id_value_2" name="value" type="radio" value="3" />
<input id="id_value_3" name="value" type="radio" value="4" />
<input id="id_value_4" name="value" type="radio" value="5" />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" value="{% trans "Rate" %}"
        onclick="return $(this.form).find('option:selected').length == 1;">
</button>
```

but for visual purpose I want to use a star rating system instead of radio buttons so I changed to:

```
<select id="id_value" form="form_id">
            <option id="id_value_0" name="value" value="1">1</option>
            <option id="id_value_1" name="value" value="2">2</option>
            <option id="id_value_2" name="value" value="3">3</option>
            <option id="id_value_3" name="value" value="4">4</option>
            <option id="id_value_4" name="value" value="5">5</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" value="{% trans "Rate" %}"
        onclick="return $(this.form).find('option:selected').length == 1;">
</button>
```

So basically if I use the inputs, the selected radio value gets sent to the beckend but if I want to use selected option the value does not send anything to the backend. How can I change the submit button to get the selected value and send it to the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't put `name` on `<option>` you put it on `<select>` and the value of that is submitted based on it's selected option(s)

```
<select id="id_value" form="form_id" name="value>
   <option  value="1">1</option>
```